# How do I send a PUT request to API without getting 415 error

Tags: python, json, http

I'm trying to send a PUT request to an API with a Python script but keep getting a 415 error.
Can someone point out my mistake?
Here is my code:

```
for item in data:
    print(type(item["Status"]))
    print(type(item["Text"]))
    r = requests.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ratings/" + str(item["id"]) , {"Text": item["Text"], "Status": item["Status"]})
    print(r)
```

This is the 415 message:

```
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'str'>
<Response [415]>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'str'>
<Response [415]>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'str'>
<Response [415]>
<class 'numpy.str_'>
<class 'str'>
<Response [415]>
```

server error:

```
May  7 16:31:30 |DEBUG| May  7 16:31:30 |P3mWARN W |ERSPUT  (415)  api/ratings/4.json/hosth"127.0.0.1:8004" =pi"127.0.0.1" =0.0.1" .0.1" .msch0.1" ch0.1" s0.1" .1" s3936mschemes"https"36mschemehemettps"36mscheme=s"36mschemehememeay  7 16:31:30 |DEBUG| PHP    Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "ApiPlatform\Core\EventListener\AddFormatListener::onKernelRequest". path="C:\\xampp\\php\\php-cgi.exe" php="7.4.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you want is do a request passing an object as a parameter, using key `data` as a parameter.

Also add the headers for `application/json`.
try this:

```
headers = {'Content-type':'application/json', 'Accept':'application/json'}
r = request.put("http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/ratings/" + str(item["id"]),
                                                       data=item,
                                                       headers=headers)
```

Comment: Can you put the output from the server? What's the error your server shows?

Comment: Can you test using headers? Just update answer. @LarsAssen